# Dungeon Raid on PC?

Tags: dungeon-raid

Does anyone know anything about running Dungeon Raid on PC?

I wanted to buy that game, but unfortunately I can't afford an iPad or iPhone (here in Brazil those are very expensive).

Comment: They should make a port to PC and sell it on Steam \o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard anything. You can visit the [Dungeon Raid website](http://dungeonraid.atspace.com), where you'll find contact info.  E-mail the developers and request a PC version.

Also note that it runs on iPod Touch. Maybe you can find one used.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to play iOS games without an iOS device.

As of now, I don't believe the games devs have announced any intentions to port the title to any other platforms.

So no, it can't be run on your PC.

Comment: There are ports of Angry Birds running on PC :-)

Comment: That's a port. Not someone running the iOS version on the PC.